# Can LINQ be used to extract rows from a DataTable that meet a specified column value

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am writing a C# application that needs to extract rows from a DataTable that contain a specific value in one of the columns.

Example data would be like;

```
ID      Value1   Value2
-----------------------
1       AAA      BBB
2       MMM      CCC
1       RRR      999
2       ZZZ      XXX
```

I want to extract rows for ID = 1 and then ID = 2 into separate new DataTables.  Is there anything in LINQ that can accomplish this?  I will also have the situation where I will have two columns that are key values for rows.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: LINQ can be used to query the `DataTable` and produce `IEnumerable<T>` results.  It's then up to you to use that result as appropriate, e.g. insert the data into a new `DataTable`.

Answer (score 1):

**A very easy Method :)**

```
List<DataTable> Tables = new List<DataTable>();

//Have some loop to search each item
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from MyRows in Olddt.AsEnumerable()
                             where MyRows.Field<int>("ID") == ItemToSearch || 
                             MyRows.Field<string>("Value1").Contains(ItemToSearch ) || 
                             MyRows.Field<string>("Value2").Contains(ItemToSearch )
                             select MyRows;
DataTable dtNew = query.CopyToDataTable();
Tables.Add(ss); // Add New Datatable to Collection of DataTables.
```

Comment: That filters the rows into a new `DataTable`, doesn't split into multiple `DataTable`s.

Comment: I should have worded my question better.  I can make multiple passes doing this, each time changing the search criteria.

Comment: This works for me, but there is an issue I have hit.  In some cases the starting data table lacks rows that meet the search criteria.  I get an exception thrown.  Is there a way to make sure that I can deal with this?  I can put in a try/catch structure to not just crash the program.  But I would need to know how to distinguish the lack of data vs. something more serious.  Is there a way to check for a count of rows that meet the search criteria before actually trying to retrieve the data?